# Java - How to keep running on exception

Tags: java, exception

This question seems pretty simple. How do I keep running my application on an exception.

For instance how would I go about doing this.

Server application tries to run on port 1234, but it's not available. Normally it would just crash. But how can I make it keep running and say; Would you like to try another port?

Or if we're trying to load a file which doesn't exists. How do I avoid the program from crashing, but just display a little message saying the it was unable to load the file.

How is this done?

Comment: catch the exception

Comment: How do you live a life without try catch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [try catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

```
try{
 //Where exception may happen
}catch(Exception e){//Exception type. Exception covers it all.
 //Print error if you would like or do something else
}finally{//Finally is optional, as the code in here will run regardless of an exception.
}
//program continues
```

Most try-catch blocks do not have `finally` at the end.  You will use `finally` if you need code to be run whether or not there was an exception.  [More information about the finally block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I have completely misunderstood the purpose of a try catch :)

Comment: also after the catch you can add finally{} to run anything if it fails.  You often use this for closing streams if they cause an exception.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? Isn't that what catch does?

Comment: @KaareZ The code inside the catch is run only if there is an exception.  If there is no exception it does not run.  Finally runs only after both the code in the try and catch is complete.  That is why it is called finally.

Comment: Does that mean a catch can fail? If no, why would you put code in the finally, when it could be in the catch?

Comment: @KaareZ I edited my post to add information about the finally block.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I still don't understand why you would use it?

What would the difference be between:

try {
    code 1
} catch (Exception e) {
    code 2
} finally {
    code 3
}

And


try {
    code 1
} catch (Exception e) {
    code 2
}
   code 3

Comment: @KaareZ say you create an input stream outside the try catch and you open it inside the try block.  When you are done with the stream you need to close it.  Sure you could do that without the finally, but if you return in the catch block, code after it will not run.  Even if you return inside the catch block the finally block will still run.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example where a catch would fail, but the finally does execute:

```
int number = 0;

try {
    number = 1 / 0;
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Nooooo!");
} finally {
    System.out.println("What just happened?");
}

System.out.println(number);
```

This outputs:

```
What just happened?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at ...
```

The catch failed to execute because it only catches IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions and not ArithmeticExceptions, which is what you get when you try to divide by zero.

Comment: You should give an explanation about what each part does.  Also the exception in your case will throw a ArithmeticException not a IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Ok, I added some explanations.

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering from same problem but my case was the exception thrown from binary tree class which terminated the program and I wanted it to continue execution.So, your problem can be solved by below written code.

```
do{
try{
    //get the value for port 
    //it may throw exception

  }
 catch(Exception e){
   // handle exception
  }
 //ask for yes or no to continue
}while(choice);
```

Well, this will keep asking for port values as long as you want.Use loops to ask values for ports continuously.

Remember:You can add code after catch block but not in between try and catch block.